# Why Mysql JOIN Query - Full SCAN not using Index

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb, query-optimization

when I select query in only one table, we got response with using index, But when using join statemnt In query, mysql Full scan on table?

First query

```
select *
    from t_deposit_trx
    where remit_tx_id = '3a33ff14-8d31-45d0-b64f-8a251c4b19a5'
```

> 1  SIMPLE  t_deposit_trx   ref t_deposit_trx_remit_tx_id_index
>       t_deposit_trx_remit_tx_id_index 110 const   1   Using index condition

Second Query

```
select tx_id
from t_settle_trx
where report_date >= '2019-03-01'
  and report_date <= '2019-03-16'
  and tx_type = 'CANCEL'
```

> 1 SIMPLE  t_settle_trx    range   t_settle_trx_report_date_tx_type_index  t_settle_trx_report_date_tx_type_index  196     5263    Using index condition

the 2 query is well operated.
using index and speed is good.

But join the two table, it's very slow.

```
select * from t_deposit_trx
force index (t_deposit_trx_remit_tx_id_index)
where remit_tx_id in (
  select tx_id
  from t_settle_trx
  where report_date >= '2019-03-01'
    and report_date <= '2019-03-02'
    and tx_type = 'CANCEL'
)
```

> 1 PRIMARY t_deposit_trx   ALL                 55724
>   1 PRIMARY t_settle_trx    range   t_settle_trx_report_date_tx_type_index  t_settle_trx_report_date_tx_type_index  196     299 Using index condition; Using where; FirstMatch(t_deposit_trx); Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)

we can see above result..
t_settle_trx use range scan and get tx_id and next I hope the query use index 
"t_settle_trx_report_date_tx_type_index" 
But it use Full scan..

I dont' know why?

Comment: Does it make a difference is you use a JOIN than a `IN (SELECT`. What MySQL/MariaDB version? What is table structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE t_deposit_trx`)? Making t_settle_trx_report_date_tx_type_index have tx_type before report date would be good these queries, look at the length used in the explain.

Comment: I already join query and then both table use full scan. mariadb version is 10.1.29-MariaDB-1~xenial. thank you.

Comment: In my little experience, using `IN` is much slower than `JOIN` like `INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN`. But I did find some people experience slower `JOIN` than `IN`.

Comment: When you ask a question about query optimization, you should include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table in the query. Otherwise we can only guess at the indexes you currently have, as well as other table options. For example. In this case, I wonder if the join is comparing strings with different collations, and therefore cannot use an index for the comparison.

Comment: thank you very much Bill Karwin. I appreciate that your comment.  I check out the 2 tables collation and found it's different. One is not set. and the other is utf8 ..

Comment: @jaechoi - "utf8" is a `CHARACTER SET`; check the `COLLATIONs`.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

Query 2 is *not* optimal.  Turn the index around:

```
INDEX(tx_type, report_date)
```

That is, put the column(s) tested with `=` *first*, regardless of cardinality.

`IN ( SELECT ... )` is *not* a `JOIN`.  (In newer versions, it *might* be converted into a `JOIN`.)

Give this a try:

```
SELECT  d.*
    FROM  t_settle_trx AS s
    JOIN  t_deposit_trx AS d  ON s.tx_id = d.remit_tx_id
    WHERE  s.tx_type = 'CANCEL'
      AND  s.report_date >= '2019-03-01'
      AND  s.report_date <  '2019-03-01' + INTERVAL 2 DAY

s: INDEX(tx_type, report_date, tx_id)
d: INDEX(remit_tx_id)
```

Think of this `SELECT` with a `JOIN` as starting with the table that has `WHERE` clauses.

(Note:  I arranged the tables and the order of where-clauses so you can see how the Optimizer is thinking.  The order of tables and the order of where-clauses is not relevant; the Optimizer will rearrange as it sees fit.)

My formulation should

- make good use of indexes on both tables.
- avoid full table scans
- do all the filtering on the *first* table (s) that it looks at

Full table scan is *not* neccessarily a bad thing.  If *most* of a table will be touched anyway, it is actually *faster* to simply scan the table and not bounce between the index's BTree and the data's BTree.  (Your *specific* case had other deficiencies; I focused on them.)

```
INDEX(tx_type, report_date, tx_id)
```

is "covering" in that all the columns needed by the query are found in the one index.  "Covering" gives you a slight extra performance boost.  It is indicated in `EXPLAIN` by `Using index` (not `Using index condition`).

With tx_seq, this may be optimal:

```
INDEX(tx_type, report_date, tx_seq)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this will not be slower than your first query:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t_deposit_trx t1 
INNER JOIN t_settle_trx t2
ON t1.remit_tx_id=t2.tx_id
WHERE t2.report_date >= '2019-03-01'
AND t2.report_date <= '2019-03-02'
AND t2.tx_type='CANCEL';
```

Comment: yes, your query is faster then before, but still t_deposit_trx table full scan... that's the problem. thank you

Comment: Ok, now I understand your concern. Its not about which method is faster. Not much I can do here ;)

Comment: Have an index on `t_settle_trx(tx_type,report_date,tx_id)`. There should be a index on  `t_deposit_trx(remit_tx_id)` too. Please show your table structures with `SHOW CREATE TABLE t_settle_trx` and `t_deposit` next time, guessing what is in an index and what types things by the name isn't reliable and will delay you getting a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Guys..
Thank you about your interest about my question.

Above 2 tables has same index structure in staging environment and production environment.
and using galera cluster.

What I am actually wonder is why they use different "execution plan"?
Especially in production environment, JOIN query is very slow.

What I do yesterday is..

```
select * from t_deposit_trx
where remit_tx_id in (
  select tx_id
  from t_settle_trx
  where report_date >= '2019-03-01'
    and report_date <= '2019-03-02'
    and tx_type = 'CANCEL'
)
```

I change this query slightly like

```
select * from t_deposit_trx
where tx_seq in (
  select tx_seq 
  from t_settle_trx
  where report_date >= '2019-03-01'
    and report_date <= '2019-03-02'
    and tx_type = 'CANCEL'
)
```

and then first t_settle_trx "range scan" and the second t_deposit_trx "Index scan"..
but the tow tx_seq value is different value. It didn't have any relation ship.
It's only test if they can use index when join query.

You know what I mean?
that means they can use index when joining.

So Is there any environment variable problem or Key Length limit or anythinig?

Thank you for reading me.

Comment: Now you need different indexes, perhaps on both tables, due to `tx_seq` instead of `tx_id`.